# How do I run a .msi file using golang?

Tags: go

I'm writing a function that will run an msi file by taking in the applications path as a parameter. Right now the function is returning an error code stating that the application's path is not a valid Win32 application. This function works for .exe files, but not .msi files. How can I refactor it to work for .msi files?

```
func Run(application string) {
    cmd := exec.Command(application)
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("cmd.Run() failed with %s\n", err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simply run it through  windows's command line

```
   func main(){    
    c := exec.Command("cmd", "/C", "msiexec /a \"pathtotheMSIfile\"")
    if err := c.Run(); err != nil { 
        fmt.Println("Error: ", err)
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is closer than I was able to get. I am now getting the Error: exit status 1619, which equates to the msi file being in a subfolder. I do not understand how this is the issue as I am supplying the full path to the msi file as the "pathtotheMSIfile" argument.

Comment: try to make the following test: move the MSI file into your golang execution folder, and call it by his name
Error code 1619 = "This installation package could not be opened. Verify that the package exists and that you can access it, or contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid Windows Installer package.

Answer (score 1):

Create a file like this:

```
//go:generate mkwinsyscall -output zmsi.go msi.go
//sys msiInstallProduct(file string, command string) (e error) = msi.MsiInstallProductW
package main

func main() {
   msiInstallProduct(`C:\file.msi`, "")
}
```

Then build:

```
go generate
go mod init msi
go mod tidy
go build
```

https://github.com/golang/sys/tree/master/windows/mkwinsyscall